# HashSet<T> fundamental things

Tags: c#, .net, generics, hashset

I'm reading about tests and I have the following question:

Is it true regarding the System.Collections.Generic.HashSet ?

> HashSet provides functionality for "conceptual sets" where the rules
>   for membership can be specified without actually creating all of the
>   items

I read appox 20 pages about HashSet doc and I never found answer the question. Truly to say, I even don't understand the question correctly :) What means and is it truly sentence?

Comment: I don't understand that question too :) I don't even understand what *rules for membership can be specified without actually creating all of the items* mean. I think you taken it from [here](http://mrgautamg.blogspot.ae/2013/11/asp-net-35-c-mcq.html) my advice is stop reading it.

Comment: Maybe that's for a different platform such as Java? They have a set interface so you can plug in what ever logic you want.

Comment: @usr If OP has taken it from the link in my comment, it is about Asp.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you quoted that from, it doesn't appear in the documentation at all. To actually quote from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The `HashSet<T>` class is based on the model of mathematical sets and provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys of the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `Hashtable` collections. In simple terms, the `HashSet<T>` class can be thought of as a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` collection without values.

So it is a collection, containing actual values. The sentence you quoted there is false.

That being said, you *could* create an `ISet<T>` implementation that works that way, e.g. representing numbers in a set as ranges. But trying to do that with a vanilla `HashSet<T>` will quickly break down.